# What button event should I use to confirm a html form?

Tags: javascript, forms, events

Using Javascript, no framework, what button event should I use to confirm form when I wish not redirect? I expect to use either left mouse button or keyboard to confirm the form.

I used this element:

```
<button type="button" value="1">Save</button>
```

Using type="submit" with "submit" event is no solution for me because this creates redirection (values the from are lost). So I use type "button".

When I use

```
document.getElementById("advanced_form").addEventListener("click", saveOptions);
```

This even "click" is used with mouse. But there is possibility that the user will use keyboard instead mouse to submit form. So I suspect the form would not react to keyboard confirm action. I did not find any event related to button being pressed. So how to solve this problem?

Comment: *"Using type="submit" with "submit" event is no solution for me because this creates redirection (values the from are lost)"* That doesn't make any sense. Using the `submit` event doesn't magically cause any "redirection" or loss of form values. Can you give more detail about what you think is happening when you use it? `submit` is the right event for handling form submission.

Comment: I think the best way to do this is to use a submit button.

Comment: @T.J. Crower: What happened is when I clicked the button the values which were in the form disapeared and so I understood it that the form was reloaded without any values. But the values should not disappear, the behaviour which I need is like in a normal Browser Window (WINAPI), so when you need to save options, the page will not clear the values. If I'd want to close the form, I'd close the tab (html page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could still use ´type="submit"´ in combination with ´e.preventDefault();´ to aviod the redirect.

I hope this helped, good luck.

Comment: The `click` event on a `type="submit"` button does **not** reliably fire when the form is submitted with the keyboard or assistive technology. It does on some forms in some browsers, but it depends on the form content and the browser. `preventDefault` is indeed the solution, but not with a `type="submit"` element; with the form's `submit` event.

Answer (score 0):

From your clarifying comment:

> What happened is when I clicked the button the values which were in the form disapeared and so I understood it that the form was reloaded without any values.

Submitting a form...submits the form. What you get back as a result depends entirely on what the server sends back.

> But the values should not disappear, the behaviour which I need is like in a normal Browser Window (WINAPI)

That **is** normal.

> ...the page will not clear the values. If I'd want to close the form, I'd close the tab (html page).

That *isn't* normal. Normal is for the form to go away and be replaced by the result of submitting it.

But you can do that with the `submit` event, just use `event.preventDefault()` within the `submit` event to prevent the form submission:

```
document.getElementById("the-form").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevents the form from being submitted
});
```

That event will reliably fire whether the user used the mouse, keyboard, or assistive technology to submit the form. The `click` event on a submit button will **not** reliably fire when the form is submitted with the keyboard or assistive technology.

Comment: Why server??? I can be offline! JS works on client side. This has nothing to do with server.

Comment: @user1141649: That's fine, just prevent the default action (submitting the form, which expects there to be somewhere to submit it *to*). Note that having a form you're not submitting anywhere is *unusual*, and so would be a *really useful thing* to put in the question.

Comment: It is pretty usual to use html forms + javascript in browser extension / addon without being send to server.

Comment: @user1141649: And yet, writing extensions is unusual. Again, no biggie, just include the information next time so people know when answering. Doesn't change the fundamental above: Use the `submit` event, and cancel the default action.

Comment: **For you** it is unusual.

Comment: @user1141649: Oh for crying out loud. No. It's unusual, objective fact. # of people writing JavaScript for web pages/web applications/Windows metro apps/etc.: Into the millions. # of people writing extensions: Into the thousands, *tops*. I fail to understand why you keep going on in this way, but I'm done.

Answer (score -1):

You can use submit button, but you need to handle submit action. Try this (with jquery):

```
<input class="submit_button" type="submit" value="Save" />
<script>
function submit_form(e)
{
    if (check_form_submit()) {
        // check your data here

        $(this).submit();
        return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}
$(function() {
    $('.submit_button').parents('form').submit(submit_form);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should still use the submit input type but you need to prevent the default action so that the page doesn't reload.
If you are using jQuery this snippet should help.

```
$('#my-form').submit(function(ev) {
ev.preventDefault(); // to stop the form from submitting
// Your code here
this.submit(); // If you want to submit at the end
});
```